# JavaFX get child by bounds

Tags: java, javafx, bounds

I have a VBox that contain some 100 to 2000 HBoxes. The VBox is placed inside a ScrollPane. Is there is any way to get a HBox at some bounds in that VBox. For example get a HBox at 500px of VBox y position. And each HBox height maybe different. I searched over google, but I got only get position of HBox, not HBox by position.

Comment: There isn't anything in the API to do this directly. Of course, you can easily iterate through the child list of the `VBox` and find the first (or all) whose bounds contain the point of interest. But why do you need this functionality? Maybe there is an easier way to do what you are trying to do anyway.

Comment: @James_D hi buddy, actually what i am trying do, in scroll pane, after fast scroll, we dont know which HBoxes are visible in the view port area. but we have the viewport bounds, i trying to identify which HBoxes are currently visible in viewport area.

i tried with for loop through the children list. seems it is working as good 100 to 200 HBoxes in VBox. But if Hboxes count is grow more than 2000, it is very very bad. can you please suggest a better way to achieve this